# filtering soup.find_all("div", {"class":"name"} ) in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

there are some  divs with class "name" in body and others in header
I want to get only those in body here an example of html code below

```
<header>
    <div class="header-thump">
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="name"><a href="https://www.asrar-co.">product in body</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<body>
    <div class="product-thumb">
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="name"><a href="https://www.asrar-co.">product in body</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and here is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from itertools import product, zip_longest

headers = None
result = requests.get("https://www.asrar-co.com/ar/%D8%A7%D8%B8%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B1-%D8%B5%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%A9?sort=pd.name&order=ASC&limit=5000", headers=headers)

product_title = []
product_price = []

src = result.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
# my prroblem is here
product_titles = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"name"} )
product_prices = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"price-normal"} )

for i in range(len(product_titles)):
    product_title.append(product_titles[i].text)

print(product_title)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are products which don't have normal price, but are "*in sale*" (with `class="price-new"`). You have to handle this case too. For example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


result = requests.get(
    "https://www.asrar-co.com/ar/%D8%A7%D8%B8%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B1-%D8%B5%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%A9?sort=pd.name&order=ASC&limit=5000",
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, "lxml")

data = []
for product in soup.select(".product-thumb"):
    name = product.select_one(".name").get_text(strip=True)
    price = product.select_one(".price-new, .price-normal").get_text(strip=True)
    data.append([name, price])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "Price"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                Name       Price
0   ستيكي نيل اظافر لاصقه جذابه متعدده المقاسات وسهله التركيب 24 حبة   S.R 22.87
1                                   العرايس مزيل طلاء الاظافر 120 مل    S.R 5.75
2                                  كولير لوكس غراء اظافر شفاف 7 جرام   S.R 11.50
3      كولورز ستوديو اظافر صناعية لاصقة 28 قطعة 7 مقاسات NO. CS-NT01   S.R 17.95
4      كولورز ستوديو اظافر صناعية لاصقة 28 قطعة 7 مقاسات NO. CS-NT03   S.R 17.95
5      كولورز ستوديو اظافر صناعية لاصقة 28 قطعة 7 مقاسات NO. CS-NT17   S.R 17.95
6      كولورز ستوديو اظافر صناعية لاصقة 28 قطعة 7 مقاسات NO. CS-NT18   S.R 17.95
7      كولورز ستوديو اظافر صناعية لاصقة 28 قطعة 7 مقاسات NO. CS-NT19   S.R 17.95
8      كولورز ستوديو اظافر صناعية لاصقة 28 قطعة 7 مقاسات NO. CS-NT21   S.R 17.95
9      كولورز ستوديو اظافر صناعية لاصقة 28 قطعة 7 مقاسات NO. CS-NT22   S.R 17.95
10     كولورز ستوديو اظافر صناعية لاصقة 28 قطعة 7 مقاسات NO. CS-NT24   S.R 17.95
11                               فولتين سائل مغذي ومقوي للأظافر 8 مل  S.R 132.94
12            جليز ايزي برس 24 اظافر صناعية لاصقة 10 مقاسات JE60-005   S.R 16.75
13            جليز ايزي برس 24 اظافر صناعية لاصقة 10 مقاسات JE60-006   S.R 16.75
14            جليز ايزي برس 24 اظافر صناعية لاصقة 10 مقاسات JE60-007   S.R 16.75
15            جليز ايزي برس 24 اظافر صناعية لاصقة 10 مقاسات JE60-010   S.R 16.75
16            جليز ايزي برس 24 اظافر صناعية لاصقة 10 مقاسات JE60-011   S.R 16.75
17            جليز ايزي برس 24 اظافر صناعية لاصقة 10 مقاسات JE60-012   S.R 16.75
18            جليز ايزي برس 24 اظافر صناعية لاصقة 10 مقاسات JE60-014   S.R 16.75
19            جليز ايزي برس 24 اظافر صناعية لاصقة 10 مقاسات JE60-016   S.R 16.75
20                                      جليز غراء اظافر وردي 10 جرام   S.R 12.32
21                         موكا اظافر صناعية لاصقة رقم 100 حبة E-117    S.R 8.80
22                          موكا اظافر صناعية لاصقة رقم 100 حبة E-15    S.R 8.80
23                           موكا اظافر صناعية لاصقة رقم 100 حبة E-2    S.R 8.80
24                          موكا اظافر صناعية لاصقة رقم 100 حبة E-21    S.R 8.80
25                          موكا اظافر صناعية لاصقة رقم 100 حبة E-27    S.R 8.80
26                              موكا أظافر اصطناعية رقم 100 حبة E-52    S.R 8.80
27                              موكا أظافر اصطناعية رقم 100 حبة E-96    S.R 8.80
28                              موكا أظافر اصطناعية رقم 100 حبة E-98    S.R 8.80
29                              موكا أظافر اصطناعية رقم 100 حبة E-99    S.R 8.80
30                           جليز - اظافر بيوتي 100 حبه مديل JR 3148   S.R 12.32
31                         نيو جولدن أظافر اصطناعية رقم (E-2) 100حبه    S.R 8.80
```